# Adding html via Jquery but page just keeps refreshing

Tags: jquery, html

I don't have access to change the html directly on page so I'm using jquery to add some text. I have this code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if(window.location.href='http://somepage.com')
 { 
    $(".rightborder.eq(2)").append("<p>some text</p>");
}
```

The problem is that the text gets added but the page just keeps refreshing, like its doing a loop which cannot end. Can anyone see why?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning new href property, you need to check it instead:

```
if(window.location.href === 'http://somepage.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is to initialize try `==` for comparision

And

```
$(".rightborder").eq(2).append("<p>some text</p>");
```

instead of

```
$(".rightborder.eq(2)").append("<p>some text</p>");


   if (window.location.href == 'http://somepage.com') {
        $(".rightborder").eq(2).append("<p>some text</p>");
   }
```

Comment: I was just about to tell you that you'd made the same error as in the original post - then you corrected it ;)

Comment: @StephenOrr Yeah it was copy paste and working on it after.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if(window.location.href ==='http://somepage.com')
     { 
        $(".rightborder").eq(2).append("<p>some text</p>");
     }
});
```

Use `===`(exactly equal to- equal value and equal type) not `=`(used to assign values) . **[Javascript Comparison Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)**

And you cannot use `.eq(2)` in that way.

Answer (score 0):

your `if` condition is wrong..You should use the `comparision` operator instead of `assignment`  operator.

Use this..

```
if(window.location.href == 'http://somepage.com')
```

Also correct the below code

```
$(".rightborder.eq(2)").append("<p>some text</p>");
```

to this

```
   $(".rightborder").eq(2).append("<p>some text</p>");
```